# How to register services in ASP.NET Boilerplate using IocManager?

Tags: asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, registration, aspnetboilerplate

For ASP.NET Core, I know how to register services using `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x => {
    var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
    var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
    return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
});
```

How can I register same services using `IocManager` in my ASP.NET Boilerplate (ASP.NET Core) project so that I can use them in my application services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## AddSingleton

```cs
IocManager.Register<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

## AddScoped + Factory

```cs
IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
    Component
        .For<IUrlHelper>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel =>
        {
            var actionContext = kernel.Resolve<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
            var factory = kernel.Resolve<IUrlHelperFactory>();
            return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
        })
        .LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager>() // ASP.NET Core
     // .LifestylePerWebRequest()                    // ASP.NET MVC 5
);
```

---

## References

- ASP.NET Boilerplate documentation: [Dependency Injection — Custom/Direct Registration](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#custom-direct-registration)
- IoC PerWebRequest and Factory pattern: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#3921](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3921)
- IScopedDependency: [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#3945](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3945)